# rails undefined method - unix/ruby version pb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version

First off, I'm French so please forgive my language errors :$.

I have two rails environments set up. One at home which I use for basically developing the web app and the other one is running on a server.

For some reason, last time I pushed the web app from my personal computer to the server I got the following error in a controller:

```
NoMethodError in SocialsController#create
undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass
```

the controller looks like this:

```
  def create
    if !break?
      @social = Social.new(params[:social])
      @social.profile_id = current_account.profile.id
      if @social.save
        render :inline => "<script>window.onload = window.close()</script>"
      else
        render :action => "edit"
      end
    else
      render :action => "error"
    end
  end
```

and here is break:

```
def break? 
  @break = false
  current_account.profile.socials.all.each do |s|
    if params[:social][:email] == s.email && params[:social][:network] == s.network
      @break = true
      break
    end
  end
  return @break
end
```

I should mention that I have nested models like this: account has_one profile has_many socials

The thing is it's the exact same project file with the same controllers, the exact same database. the only thing that changes is the Rails version. here are the main differences:

home:
- MacOS X snow leopard
- ruby v1.8.7
- rails v3.0.4
- sqlite3 v3.7.5
- gem v1.5.2

server: 
- Linux debian 5.0
- ruby v1.9.2p0
- rails v3.0.4
- sqlite3 v3.7.5
- gem v1.6.1

Did I get anything wrong here?

Comment: How is current_account populated? The error indicates that this variable is nil, possibly meaning that you're not signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a shot in the dark here, but it looks like your `current_user` object is `nil` on the server -- which probably means that you're either logged out or you need to try logging out (or clearing cookies) and logging back in.